# Replace and cut or nested replace (x2) in one line (batch-file)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filenames, command-line-arguments

How to transform in one cmd line current date & time into file name without spaces?

I know how to do it in two lines:

```
set file_name=file_%date%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
rem echo %file_name% return "file_2015-08-01- 85012" and it's not ok
```

(contain space)

```
set file_name=%file_name: =0%
echo echo %file_name% return "file_2015-08-01-085012" and it's ok
```

(no spaces)

but I can't run program in *.bat file - I have to run "original" *.exe which require all parameters in one line.

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389

Answer (score 0):

```dos
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=:/- " %a in ('robocopy "|" . /njh^|find "|"') do echo %a-%b-%c-%d%e%f
```

Comment: It should be passed to *.exe program as one of parameters. You cant pass "for ..." as parameter - one solution is to pass "file_%date%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%", but I wan "0" instead of " " (space).

Comment: @jakson, The idea is not to use `exefile for /f ...`, but `for /b ..... exefile file_%a-%b-%c-%d%e%f`. In previous code replace the `echo` with the executable